# Verrtical / Hoizontal WIndows

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, workspaces, 17.10, workspace-switcher

Just moved from Unity to Gnome with the update to 17.10.
Can the Workspaces be made to go left right / east west as in Unity, rather than north south / up down ?
After three years of use, my fingers are really used to left / right.
Does anybody know how to do this ?